# How to activate javascript links with zombie.js

Tags: node.js, zombie.js

I am trying to get get zombie.js to activate a link that uses javascript. The page I am testing it on is:

```
 <html>
  <body>
  <div id="test123">
  START_TEXT
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:go()">GO</a><br/>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  go = function() {
  var el = document.getElementById("test123");
  el.innerHTML = "CHANGED";
  }
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

The Script I am using is:

```
var zombie = require("zombie");
var browser = new zombie.Browser;

browser.visit( "http://localhost:8000/testpage.html",
        function() {
                browser.clickLink("GO", function(e, browser, status) {
                        var temp = browser.text("div#test123");
                        console.log("content:", temp);
                  });
});
```

I get the error message:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Cannot load resource: javascript:go()
    at History._resource (/home/julian/temp/node_modules/zombie/lib/zombie/history.coffee:75:15)
    at History._pageChanged (/home/julian/temp/node_modules/zombie/lib/zombie/history.coffee:60:21)
    at History._assign (/home/julian/temp/node_modules/zombie/lib/zombie/history.coffee:213:19)
    at Object.location (/home/julian/temp/node_modules/zombie/lib/zombie/history.coffee:51:24)
    at Object.click (/home/julian/temp/node_modules/zombie/lib/zombie/jsdom_patches.coffee:31:59)
    at Object.dispatchEvent (/home/julian/temp/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/level2/html.js:480:47)
    at /home/julian/temp/node_modules/zombie/lib/zombie/eventloop.coffee:130:16
    at EventLoop.perform (/home/julian/temp/node_modules/zombie/lib/zombie/eventloop.coffee:121:7)
    at EventLoop.dispatch (/home/julian/temp/node_modules/zombie/lib/zombie/eventloop.coffee:129:19)
    at Browser.dispatchEvent (/home/julian/temp/node_modules/zombie/lib/zombie/browser.coffee:220:30)
```

When I use

`browser.evaluate("go()")`

it works.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it doesn't seem to understand `javascript:code` hrefs. Perhaps you can get the url, remove the javascript:-section and evaluate it?

Disclaimer: I haven't used zombie.js myself yet.

Answer (score 6):

Zombie.js doesn't handle links with "javascript:" on href (at the time of this writing).

I fixed it by adding 3 lines to the source code. Look for /node_modules/zombie/lib/zombie/history.coffee and add the 3 lines commented with FIX (beware that in .coffee you must respect indentation, ie. use 2 spaces):

```
# Location uses this to move to a new URL.
_assign: (url)->
  url = @_resolve(url)

  # FIX: support for javascript: protocol href
  if url.indexOf("javascript:")==0
    @_browser.evaluate(url.substr("javascript:".length))
    return

  was = @_stack[@_index]?.url # before we destroy stack
  @_stack = @_stack[0..@_index]
  @_stack[++@_index] = new Entry(this, url)
  @_pageChanged was
```

I probably should fork zombie.js on github.com and put this into a Pull Request, but until then you are welcome to do use this snippet, or make that pull request before me.

Answer (score -1):

The [zombie.js API](http://zombie.labnotes.org/API.html) says it takes a CSS selector or the link text as the first parameter for `browser.clickLink()`. So your code should work.

But try adding an id to the link, if you have control over the page, and using a CSS selector

```
browser.clickLink('#thelink', function(e, browser, status) {
  var temp = browser.text("div#test123");
  console.log("content:", temp);
});
```

Comment: I tried that, and the result is the same. The link is found, the problem resides in the javascript:go() part. Other links do work.

Comment: Oh I see. It looks like tuhoojabotti's answer is right, it doesn't look like zombie.js supports those kind of links. There is already an [issue](https://github.com/assaf/zombie/issues/170) opened for this problem.